# connect-mongo module has a error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am using connect-mongo module to store sessions in mongodb but when I used this module, my project did't run I got  this error:

```
node_modules/connect-mongo/lib/connect-mongo.js:28
    var Store = connect.Store || connect.session.Store;
                                                ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Store' of undefined
```

And this is my session code

```
var session = require('express-session');
var db  = require('./mongo_connect');
var mongostore = require('connect-mongo');
module.exports = function(app){
    app.use(session({
        secret: 'this is a secret',
        store: new mongostore({
            db : db
        })
    }));
};
```

And I am working with

```
express : 4.9.5
mongoose : 3.8.17
connect-mongo : 0.3.3
express-session : 1.9.1
```

Is there any kind of solution for this problem,if not is there other modules that do the same?

Comment: Has my answer worked for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code

```
  var session = require('express-session');
  var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);
   var store =  new MongoStore({
     url : 'localhost',
     db : 'session_db',
     collection : 'session'
  });

 app.use(session({store: store  ,secret: 'dfjhsksdfdhfr879487',saveUninitialized: true,resave: true, cookie:{httpOnly: true, maxAge:1000*60*60*7  }}));
```